# How to show only the data that user has imported to tabular model

Tags: sql, database, asp.net-core, azure-analysis-services

So I am facing some architecture problems.

I do have created a tabular model in analysis service, and one of the models has a structure of pricing, data, etc.

My system allows importing for a user a data containing millions of records. But I do not know what is the best structure. I must show on API endpoint (ASP.NET CORE) the data the user imported, but not other users data, so should I have a new column of identity, so I could know if the data belongs to the current user?

Or maybe there are better options? Maybe keeping for every user data on a new table and new a tabular model?

Comment: Interesting idea. Is there overlap between the data one user imports and the data another user imports? Can you import all the data ahead of time and then secure it appropriately so users see only the right subset they requested? Or is “all the data” too large?

Comment: Is there a need to have data from multiple users in the same model? Or is it ok to have a separate model per user? Will the data all users import fit in memory in a single Azure Analysis Services node? What node size will be required?

Comment: The problem is that there are going be users who will import data(>500k records) to my UI, so after all, I will only have to show their imported data.  But how should I achieve this, putting a new column with userId, will make lots of duplicated info, because every 500k records will have user Id? If creating a new table and tabular model for each user doesn't sound good.
I can't import all data ahead, every user by themselves will import. For now, there is no need to have multiple users in the same model.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on *a lot* of factors, but in general, adding a user ID column is going to be the way to go architecturally. This is primarily because of the way that tabular stores the data in a compressed [column store format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-oriented_DBMS). The simplest way to explain this is that a table only holds one copy of each unique value with a dictionary of how that value links to the rest of the columns.

So let's look at how this works out an example. We'll create a table with user ID and a single data column. Because we are talking about such a narrow table, I'm going to treat a row in a relational database the same as an entry in a our tabular model.

- 100 users
- 500k records per user
- 2 columns (user id and our data column)
- 10k unique values in our data column

In a traditional relational database we would have

- 100 users x 500k records = 50 million items (ouch!)

If we were to put each user into a unique table or model in tabular we have

- 100 models (users) x 10k unique values = 1 million items (probably a bit less as each user may not have all 10k values)

However, if we put create a single table with user id and our data column we get

- 100 users in one column store + 10k unique values in a different store = 10,100 items

Granted, the individual values in tabular take up more space than they do in most relational databases but the fact that you are storing one copy of each value usually makes up for that by a huge margin.

As you can see, the reason we want to go this route is that we are adding the number of possible values for each column instead of multiplying them. The key is getting an idea of the number of unique values for each column. If you have open strings somewhere, where almost every value is unique, then the compression is going to be minimal. Since most data for analysis is based on numbers, dates, and strings that have a limited number of unique values, things compress nicely in this type of storage. It does increase the number of joins since each column is kind of its own table, but the fact that tabular runs 100% in memory makes up for that.

Hopefully that's enough to get you started. If you want to learn more about how to organize your data to be efficient in a tabular model, I would suggest learning about how a [snowflake schema works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowflake_schema). For Analysis Services Tabular specifically, [Guy in a Cube](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCFp1vaKzpfvoGai0vE5VJ0w) and [sqlbi.com](https://www.sqlbi.com/) are great resources. A lot of their content is about Power BI, but the Power BI data models are just tabular cubes. They both use the Vertipaq engine to store and query data.

Comment: But first I store it in database and after it stored I moved data to tabular model, so in database there are still be 50 millions of records, even though it will be just for backup, what to you think, is it still ok?

Comment: It depends on what else you are doing with your data, but it is possible. Dividing the commonly repeated values into separate tables can help with storage (that's where that snowflake schema becomes important). The biggest thing to keep in mind there I think is that the persistent storage can have a different schema than the tabular model and it doesn't have to be a SQL database.

Comment: As an example: If all you are doing is writing the data once and then reading it into tabular you don't need to be able to run adhoc queries on the persistent storage. Something like Blob Storage may be something to consider. The upload could be stored in a file and AAS would read all the files in that folder.